# The message CloudOTP from Android app in the end has code why

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

when we received otp from firebase received some code also  but in ios only received opt not code why?
below is some image to understand the question

[image]

Comment: That is an extra nonce/code that is used for auto-retrieval of the code on certain Android devices: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

That is an extra nonce/code that is used for auto-retrieval of the code on certain Android devices.

From the Firebase documentation on [phone number verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks):

> Auto-retrieval: on some devices, Google Play services can automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user action. (This capability might be unavailable with some carriers.) **This uses the SMS Retriever API, which includes an 11 character hash at the end of the SMS message.**

Comment: thank you so much @Frank van Puffelen